# Not able to get current user particular value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the value of `channel_id` from Firebase of the current user logged in. Below is the Image of the database:

[image: Firebase Database Image]

I am getting `null` value from it from the code given below.

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dbref = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Clients");
  dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String val =String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+val,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current user information, try the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Clients").child(userId);
 dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String names=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here you retrieve the current user id, then you add it to the path and retrieve the data.

Comment: @K132133SyedArsalanHussain check my answer

Comment: Worked but if I want to fetch name with channel_id will this work @Override public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { String channel_Id=dataSnapshot.child("channel_id").getValue().toString(); String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(); Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+val,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

Comment: what are you getting instead?

Comment: remove this toast `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+val,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` there is no `val` variable in the code

Comment: close of application while debugging without an error

Comment: Have you set the value of the `val`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 String userId=user.getUid();
 DatabaseReference dbref = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Clients").child(userId);
 dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String channel_Id=dataSnapshot.child("channel_id").getValue().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: error in line 2 of your code .getCurrentUser() is giving error

Comment: when I am hovering over it it says cannot resolve method getCurrentUser()

Comment: Worked but if I want to fetch name with channel_id will this work
 @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String channel_Id=dataSnapshot.child("channel_id").getValue().toString();
  String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+val,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Haddad's answer will work great, there's also an alternative which is to attach the listener directly to the `name` property with:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Clients/"+userId+"/name");
 dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String names=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

This last example has the advantage that it only retrieves the `name` property and nothing else, even if you later add more child properties under `userId`. This method will save you bandwidth.

Comment: He doesn't want that though, because in the comments he told me that he wants to retrieve the channel_id also not only the name property

Comment: @PeterHaddad In this case only your answer will work but the OP didn't mention that he wants to retrieve also the `channel_id` in his question. Cheers!